How to run an optimiser with feasible constraints only?
I have a pulp optimiser with a huge number of constraints. We have a condition that if the constraints are not feasible together then we need to try it on a subset of constraints that makes it feasible. I'm using backtracking to solve the issue but it's time consuming. Is there any other way I can solve it.
I am using backtracking but as expected the execution time is huge. How can I reduce the time and come up with a feasible solution in time.

Try implementing your problem with soft constraints such that it is always feasible and use penalty scoring.  (this is frequently a better strategy anyway)
For instance if you have a supply-demand model with a constraint:
supply = demand

and for some reason supply is constrained and can't make muster, you can rework the constraint as
supply + penalty = demand

(or better yet)
supply + penalty >= demand

Penalties should be included (and likely weighted appropriately so they don't eclipse best answers) in the OBJ function.  Assess the penalties with the outcome and make adjustments...
